# Am I allowed to use Javascript in my Magento Connect extension description?

Tags: extensions, magento-connect

I can't find any documentation on this and the Magento Connect admin dashboard doesn't provide any metrics as to how many people viewed my extension. I'm trying to treat the Magento Connect marketplace like any other marketing or landing page we have - I would like to track page views. I was going to post a small JS snippet but I didn't want to get banned or suspended so I decided to ask here first before I troubled a Magento rep.

The only "usage policy" I could find was directly under the Edit Extension page where you can change the verbiage. Under the description text box it says ***Some of HTML tags are allowed. No CSS is allowed.***

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is no.

Comment: Yeah, you've answered your own question. JS is not one of the allowed tags.